# Adding A Line Break To JSON File

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

I've got a Tkinter entry box (`usern`) in a window. When the user clicks on a submit button, it stores the input to a JSON file. How can I add a line break after the string has been written to the JSON file?

I've tried using the `newline="\r\n"`:

```py
with open(udf, "a", newline="\r\n") as file_object:
    json.dump(usern, file_object)
```

And the `\n`:

```py
with open(udf, "a") as file_object:
    json.dump(usern + "\n", file_object)
```

But none of it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json` module does not support adding newlines to the file when dumping data.

You can use `file_object.write("\n")` to add it to the file after dumping:

```
with open(udf, "a") as file_object:
    json.dump(usern, file_object)
    file_object.write("\n")
```

Or convert it to a string with json.dumps() and make a single write operation:

```
with open(udf, "a") as file_object:
    json_string = json.dumps(usern) + "\n"
    file_object.write(json_string)
```